# Trying to create a list & tuple from User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

For e.g. 
user input:

```
4,7,5,33,2,8
```

should give output like this:

```
['4', '7', '5', '33', '2', '8'] ('4', '7', '5', '33', '2', '8')
```

So far i have this:

```py
x = input()
z = x.split()
y = tuple(z)
print(z, y)
```

why there is extra , in the end of tuple?

Comment: **Input:
        12,56,48,86
        Output:
        ['12,56,48,86'] ('12,56,48,86',)**
why there is extra , in the end of tuple?

Comment: It represents that it is a tuple. `('...')` is just wrapped `str`. `('...',)` is `tuple` of `str`.

Comment: z = x.split(',')

Comment: And `x.split()` is splitting the string by white spaces. You should use `x.split(',')`.

Comment: This `('12,56,48,86',)` is tuple containing one element....this `('4', '7', '5', '33', '2', '8')` is  tuple containing 5 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
z = x.split(",")
```

instead of

```
z = x.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra comma is because the string you tried to split is not what you are expecting after the split. Since the split was performed on space with `x.split()` and string does not have white space so after the step the string is still a single string and then `list` and `tuple` just wrap the string and that's where the extra comma is coming from. Example `tuple('a') == ('a',)`

`x.split(',')` will create a list separate by comma and will fetch you expected results